# Understanding OpenCV camera calibration and reprojection error

Tags: python, opencv, camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I'm working with some OpenCV camera calibration code, essentially the same as this:

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html

```
obj_p[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:chessboard_size[0], 0:chessboard_size[1]].T.reshape(-1, 2) * chessboard_scale
```

A couple of tiny changes have been made but they're not really important. Here I've added the `chessboard_scale` factor, which is just the real-world dimension of each chessboard square - I want to use the camera parameters and PnP to map image pixel coordinates into real-world spatial location of features of interest, so this gives us a real-world reference factor.

`chessboard_size` is just a list, like `[4, 3]`, which allows for easy changes to the size of the chessboard reference image, if it is changed.

With the camera in a fixed position, and the same chessboard image kept flat on the floor in various different positions around the camera's field, 9 image frames are taken, and we find the chessboard corners, run the `calibrateCamera` function just like the above link, and the camera matrix, distortion matrix, translation and rotation vectors are all saved to disk.

We can then take the camera matrix etc, and do a `projectPoints` reprojection using these best-fit camera parameters, and check its accuracy - just like the example above.

```
Reprojection error: 0.33721979012691095
Reprojection error: 0.027728399041840827
Reprojection error: 0.07009944842650938
Reprojection error: 0.10604248297665374
Reprojection error: 0.09021003521251016
Reprojection error: 0.042449648057915984
Reprojection error: 0.7679437154358325
Reprojection error: 0.035574908785270136
Reprojection error: 0.04741923955415145
Mean reprojection error: 0.16940974084639945
```

Not too bad. The numbers all look quite small, which is good. The sample image which is passed in appears to be better, in terms of visible barrel distortion - it is somewhat "corrected" and straight-line features in the image are actually straight(er) lines instead of curves.

We don't want the set of calibration images to be too small - because this creates a risk of over-fitting a small number of calibration points and creating a worse global fit - and a larger number of calibration points may provide a more accurate fit in general, even though the reprojection error is not as small as it could be with a smaller data set - right?

Now, we modify this code a bit - this is the part I'm doing wrong, or my expectation is a misunderstanding.

Same camera, same scene, same chessboard. I've taken 9 new frames from the camera scene with the chessboard in different locations on the floor (so it is always in the same plane) without moving the camera.

I've now set up the object points and the image points in exactly the same way as before.

I've run `findChessboardCorners` to find the image points, just like before, and the object points are a known rectangular grid generated by numpy where every intersection point has a pitch of 7cm. Same as above.

Now, I've used `projectPoints` to calculate the reprojection error for the 9 new images.

`calibrateCamera` is *not* run this time - I use the same stored camera matrix, distortion matrix, translation vector and rotation vector stored from the output of `calibrateCamera`.

These camera calibration parameters should be meaningfully accurate across the entire camera field in general, right?

But I get reprojection values that are huge - not at all close to zero like with the points chosen for the calibration.

I was hoping to see values similar to those received when running the `projectPoints` reprojection test on the same image set used for `calibrateCamera`.

Why aren't these very small values close to zero? What am I missing?

```
Reprojection error: 161.98785675566046
Reprojection error: 255.77330602950087
Reprojection error: 131.31518741023095
Reprojection error: 205.71173597281907
Reprojection error: 119.54532276972036
Reprojection error: 329.7339468316268
Reprojection error: 33.164501816058596
Reprojection error: 371.8755721630314
Reprojection error: 358.59670901736973
Mean reprojection error: 218.63379319622425
```

Comment: can you provide images? Input, detections, output